# script code don't work unless i make refresh to the page

Tags: javascript

this is my code to drag picture but it doesn't work unless I refresh the page

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-content"> 
            <div id="containerBox" style="position:relative; margin-top:25px; border:3px solid #dfdfdf; width:100%; height:450px;overflow:hidden;" >
          <img src="images/showrooms/g_plan.png" usemap="#draggableElementMap" id="draggableElement" style=" position:absolute; top:0;left:0;cursor:move;" />      
              </div>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var el = document.getElementById('draggableElement');
          var parent = el.parentNode;
          var leftEdge = parent.clientWidth - el.clientWidth;
          var topEdge = parent.clientHeight - el.clientHeight;
          var dragObj = new dragObject(el, null, 
          new Position(leftEdge, topEdge), new Position(0, 0));
        </script>           
        </div>
```

Comment: and i used javascript found in this link

Comment: ur code is working fine on my end. are you using this library as well? http://tpstatic.com/_sotc/sites/default/files/61/source/javascript.js

Comment: when i use this library it works but the picture don't move to left it move to right only

Comment: then it's not your code, but the library you're using. always better to hit f12 and check error console to see what went wrong. edit: it's moving all directions on my browser (chrome). which browser are you on?

Comment: google chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the library you're using.

Replace

```
<script src="http://www.dreamx8.net/tahlia/2/js/plan.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="http://tpstatic.com/_sotc/sites/default/files/61/source/javascript.js"></script>
```